# PHP: Is it possible to get first two character from an array value?

Tags: php, arrays, echo

Is it possible to get / select first two character from an array value?
for example:

#### Array

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1_name
  [1] => 0_sex
  [2] => 2_age
}
```

and I need to get the first two character from each value in array's elements. So I can  get this as a result if I `echo` them.

#### Result

```
First Element is 1_
Second Element is 0_
Third Element is 2_
```

Anyone know how to solve this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use `array_map` to get new array with only the first two characters of each item:

```
$input = ['1_name', '0_sex', '2_age'];
var_dump(array_map(function($v) { return substr($v, 0, 2); }, $input));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `foreach` loop this way:

```
<?php
$a = ["1_name",
"0_sex",
"2_age"];

foreach ($a as $aa) {
    echo substr($aa, 0, 2) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1_
0_
2_
```

You can use the `array_map()` function as well to return an array.

```
array_map(function ($a) {
    return substr($a, 0, 2);
}, $input);
```

Comment: I've tried, but that give an error like this `substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: @Archibald No way dude, you should be passing the original array, look at the code carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Using indexes will work for you as well.

#### Source-Code

`index.php`

```
<?php

$array = [
    '1_name',
    '0_sex',
    '2_age'
];

echo 'First element is '  . $array[0][0] . $array[0][1] . '<br>';
echo 'Second element is ' . $array[1][0] . $array[1][1] . '<br>';
echo 'Third element is '  . $array[2][0] . $array[2][1] . '<br>';
```

#### Result

```
First element is 1_
Second element is 0_
Third element is 2_
```